# PHP imagefilter example

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation, imagefilter

I was wondering if example 1 will add the color green to every pixel or some pixels in the image?

Example 1

```
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0,255,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

pixels with RGB value 0,255,0  will remain as they are